# How do I create and use a custom function attribute in PowerShell?

Tags: function, powershell, custom-attributes

I want to be able to create and assign a custom attribute to my powershell functions.  I looked everywhere and it seems to be possible but I have not seen an example.  I have created a custom attribute in C# and am referencing the assembly in my powershell script.  However, I receive an error stating `Unexpected attribute 'MyDll.MyCustom'.`

Here is what I have:

**MyCustomAttribute in MyDll.dll:**

```
namespace MyDll
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public MyCustomAttribute(String Name)
        {
            this.Name= Name;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

**PowerShell Script:**

```
Add-Type -Path "./MyDll.dll";
function foo {
    [MyDll.MyCustom(Name = "This is a good function")]

    # Do stuff 
}
```

Of note, however, is that if I do this:

```
$x = New-Object -TypeName "MyDll.MyCustomAttribute" -ArgumentList "Hello"
```

It works fine.  So the type is clearly being loaded correctly.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemingly two things you need to change:

1. Command attributes need to syntactically precede the `param()` block.
2. Using the `Name =` specifier seems to cause the PowerShell parser to treat the attribute argument as an initializer, at which point the constructor won't get resolved.

---

```
function foo {
    [MyDll.MyCustom("This is a good function")]
    param()
    # Do stuff 
}
```